# How to increase the speed of the magento 2 back-end?

Tags: magento2, admin-panel, website-speed

How to increase the Magento 2 back-end speed? , I'm using it, and seems to be very slow, is there any setting that helps to increase the speed?

Comment: Additional information request, please. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes -
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

Increase **Max Session Size in Admin** value or set 0 to disable from **Store > Settings > Configuration -> Advanced -> System -> Security**

Check the detail:
https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/stores/security-session-management.html

Comment: what is relation between session and admin speed?

Comment: This is a new feature introduced from 2.4.3. Which is a restricted session size.

Comment: ok that's great but any relation between speed and admin session size?

Answer (score 1):

1. Separate instance for backend
2. Redis configuration
3. Remove unused extension
4. Upgrade Magento, PHP and Mysql versions.
5. Clean DB logs
6. Use proper browser ( Chrome is know to be faster )
7. Index on Schedule.
8. Review Installed Extensions
9. Configure cron to optimize use. As if cron consume resources then that too can have an impact of available resource.
   10.Delete unwanted stores, customer groups , categories or products.
10. Move orders to archive.

Edit : Additional points
12. Index management( remove or reconfigure unwanted crons especially the consume cron as this consumes lots of resources which in turn can slow down admin)
13. Try [Hyva admin](https://hyva.io/hyva-admin.html)

14. Increase memory limit
    15 Magento mode
15. Clear cache
16. Check for external calls
17. Use a fast browser( Chrome )
18. opcache module to be activated.
19. HTTP2 needed